# Safecracker Return Message on Form Submission

Tags: safecracker, entry

Suppose I have a Safecracker form that will edit channel entries. Once the entry is edited I want to display something like "Thanks for editing your entry" on the edit entry page. How would I go about displaying a thank you message on successful form submission? I do not want to be redirected to another page.

Here is example code.

```
{exp:safecracker channel="channel_name" return="channel_name/edit/ENTRY_ID" entry_id="{segment_3}"}

Title:<input name="title" type="text" value="{title}">
<br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">

{/exp:safecracker}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for an AJAX-style contact form where you display the success or failure message on the same page without a refresh. I might suggest this article: [Creating a modern AJAX contact form in ExpressionEngine](http://www.highintegritydesign.com/blog/articles/creating-a-modern-ajax-contact-form-in-expressionengine). It also mentions the difference between adding AJAX to EE's native contact form and adding AJAX to other form add-ons like Solspace's Freeform.

Alternatively, you can reload the same page/template but add another URL segment, like:

```
return="channel_name/edit/ENTRY_ID/success"
```

Then you can display a success message on that same template when the segment matches:

```
{if segment_4 == "success"}
    <p>Success message here</p>
{/if}
```

This does not offer inline validation, like AJAX will, but it is a simple option.